TeXstudio and highlighting of bibtex items (@article, @book, ...)
I moved from TeXnicCenter to the TeXstudio and wondering, if there is a way, how to make a custom syntax color for bibtex keywords like "@article", "@book", in TexStudio. It is connected with extra-keyword highlight, but I don't want change all other extra-keywords. I am trying to customize tex.qnfa without desirable effect. Can anyone help me how to solve this please? I tried this code but without success:
<context id="bibtex" format="text" transparency="true">
        <start parenthesis="bibtex:open" parenthesisWeight="20" format="asymptote:keyword">\\@article{</start>
    <stop parenthesis="bibtex:close" parenthesisWeight="20" format="asymptote:keyword">\}</stop>
    <context id="substring" format="lua:keyword" transparency="true">
        <start parenthesis="curly2:open">{</start>
        <stop parenthesis="curly2:close">}</stop>
    </context>
    <embed target="(Bib)TeX item" />
</context>


Problem solved with creation of bibtex.qnfa file:
code is:
<!DOCTYPE QNFA>
<QNFA language="BibTeX" extensions="bib" defaultLineMark="">
<!--    <sequence parenthesis="curly:open" indent="1" fold="1">{</sequence>
    <sequence parenthesis="curly:close" indent="1" fold="1">}</sequence>-->

    <context id="string" format="text" >
        <start parenthesis="string:open">&quot;</start>
        <stop parenthesis="string:close">&quot;</stop>
    </context>

    <context id="entry" format="keyword">
        <start parenthesis="curly:open" indent="1" fold="1">{</start>
        <stop parenthesis="curly:close" indent="1" fold="1">}</stop>

        <context id="substring" format="text" >
            <start parenthesis="curly2:open">{</start>
            <stop parenthesis="curly2:close">}</stop>


            <!--workaround to support {{{}}} in bibtex files -->
            <context id="subsubstring" format="text" >
                <start parenthesis="curly3:open">{</start>
                <stop parenthesis="curly3:close">}</stop>
                    <context id="subsubsubstring" format="text">
                        <start parenthesis="curly4:open">{</start>
                        <stop parenthesis="curly4:close">}</stop>
                        <context id="subsubsubsubstring" format="text" >
                            <start parenthesis="curly5:open">{</start>
                            <stop parenthesis="curly5:close">}</stop>
                        </context>
                    </context>
            </context>
        </context>
    </context>

    <context id="comment" format="comment" >
        <start parenthesis="comment:open" fold="1" >@comment$s*{</start>
        <stop parenthesis="comment:close" fold="1" >}</stop>
    </context>
    <context id="comment/single" format="comment" stayOnLine="true" >
        <start>%</start>
        <stop exclusive="false">\n</stop>
    </context>
    
    <word id="keywords/single" format="lua:keyword" >@[a-zA-Z]+</word> <--- here is the solution which colorized the bibtex keywords like lua:keywords
</QNFA>

